# Laravel Socialite Undefined Type

Tags: php, api, laravel-8

I was trying to create a Facebook Login API, but I got an undefined type in my

FbController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\User;
use Validator;
use Socialite;
use Exception;
use Auth;

class FbController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToFacebook()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    public function facebookSignin()
    {
        try {

            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
            $facebookId = User::where('facebook_id', $user->id)->first();

            if($facebookId){
                Auth::login($facebookId);
                return redirect('/dashboard');
            }else{
                $createUser = User::create([
                    'name' => $user->name,
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'facebook_id' => $user->id,
                    'password' => encrypt('john123')
                ]);

                Auth::login($createUser);
                return redirect('/dashboard');
            }

        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            dd($exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

when I used the Facebook Login, it worked but when it redirected to my dashboard it gave me a blank page...

Dashboard.blade.php

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Dashboard') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                <x-jet-welcome />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

I tried to import the class for socialite but I discovered that it was not a class, the Auth also gave me the same problem

Below are the errors displayed...

Undefined type 'Socialite'.
{
"resource": "/c:/xampp/htdocs/testing/app/Http/Controllers/FbController.php",
"owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#4",
"code": "1009",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Undefined type 'Socialite'.",
"source": "intelephense",
"startLineNumber": 23,
"startColumn": 21,
"endLineNumber": 23,
"endColumn": 30
}

Undefined Type Auth.
{
"resource": "/c:/xampp/htdocs/testing/app/Http/Controllers/FbController.php",
"owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#4",
"code": "1009",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Undefined type 'Auth'.",
"source": "intelephense",
"startLineNumber": 27,
"startColumn": 17,
"endLineNumber": 27,
"endColumn": 21
}

@Cbroe, I believe you understand it better now...

Comment: _“but I got an undefined type in my FbController.php”_  -and _where_ exactly, referring to _what_ in particular? Please quote error messages _verbatim_, instead of giving us your own shortened version of them, that lack essential detail.

Comment: Have edited the post, you can review again... @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

I tried commenting out my `use AUth;` and `use Socialite;` then I added

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
```

and it worked perfectly...